# Adding a integer to your overall score every time you get a score

Tags: swift3, int, xcode8, userdefaults

In my app you have to complete a couple questions and you are timed. At the end of the quiz you are given a score, which is a Int. I have passed that through to the main menu and my overall score displays the score i just got. I would like to know how when ever a new score is earned by the user, that the new score adds onto the overall score. My `overallScore` label displays my score and `intPassed` is the integer that is passed to the view controller. Then it would save permanently using User defaults. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Please post some code what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Get, add
var oldScore = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "overallScore")
var newScore = oldScore + intPassed

// Save
UserDefaults.standard.set(newScore, forKey: "overallScore")

// Display
overallScore.text = String(newScore)
```

Comment: Thanks @aaron i appreciate that, now i know how to do this!